# Consolide selected query under one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

You can see my query below. I made some calculations on the Findings table and ı want to more calculations with other tables. But ı can not give name to below query. Briefly ı want to continue to my code with using this query with just giving a name. (For example give new_name to table CONSOLIDE, then continue select * from CONSOLIDE and other different tables

```
select *

from

(select*, ([REPORT REF] +'-'+ [FINDING NO]) as ID_FINDING from Findings) A

left join 

(select count(case
when [RECO STATUS] = 'Closed' THEN 1
ELSE 0 end) as CLOSE_ACT_CO,
([REPORT REF] +'-'+ [FINDING NO]) as ID_FINDING
from Findings
where [RECO STATUS] = 'Closed'
group by ([REPORT REF] +'-'+ [FINDING NO])) B on (A.ID_FINDING=B.ID_FINDING)

left join 
(
select
([REPORT REF] +'-'+ [FINDING NO]) as ID_FINDING,
count(([REPORT REF] +'-'+ [RECO NO])) as ACTION_CO
from Findings
Group by 
([REPORT REF] +'-'+ [FINDING NO])
)
C on (A.ID_FINDING=C.ID_FINDING)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read - and to write.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: hi @jarlh thanks for your attention, briefly , I want to see new calculated column when I call  "Select * from Finding"  after the code above. But ı cannot see the calculated column and con not give a new name to table. In oracle I just writing begining of the query but coulndt find solution here. Create table as not working as ı see

Comment: dbname sql server